# FFTW Output differs from Matlab with the same input dataset

Tags: c, linux, matlab, fftw

I am developing an application that should analyze data coming from an A/D stage and find the frequency peaks in a defined frequency range (0-10kHz).
We are using the FFTW3 library, version 3.3.6, running on 64bit Slackware Linux (GCC version 5.3.0). As you can see in the piece of code included, we run the FFTW plan getting result in complex vector `result[]`. We have verified the operations using MATLAB. We run the FFT on MATLAB (that claims to use the same library) with exactly the same input datasets (complex `signal[]` as in the source code). We observe some difference between FFTW (Linux ANSI C) and MATLAB run. Each plot is done using MATLAB. In particular, we would like to understand (`mag[]` array):

1. Why is the noise floor so different?
2. After the main peak (at more or less 3kHz) we observe a negative peak in the Linux result, while MATLAB shows correctly a secondary peak as from the input signal.

In these examples, we do not perform any output normalization, neither in Linux nor in MATLAB. The two plots show the magnitude of the FFT results (not converted to dB).

The correct result is the MATLAB one. Does someone have any suggestion about this differences? And how can we produce with the FFTW library results closer to MATLAB?

Below the piece of C source code and the two plots.

```
//
// Part of source code:
//
//  rup[] is filled with unsigned char data coming from an A/D conversion stage (8 bit depth)
//  Sampling Frequency is 45.454 KHz
//  Frequency Range: 0 - 10.0 KHz
//  


#define CONVCOST 0.00787401574803149606

double mag[4096];
unsigned char rup[4096];
int i;

fftw_complex signal[1024];
fftw_complex result[1024];

    ...

fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(1024,signal,result,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE);

for(i=0;i<1024;i++)
{
  signal[i][REAL] = (double)rup[i] * CONVCOST;
  signal[i][IMAG] = 0.0;  
}                                   

fftw_execute(plan);

for (i = 0; i < 512; ++i) 
{   
  mag[i] = sqrt(result[i][REAL] * result[i][REAL] + result[i][IMAG] * result[i][IMAG]);
}

fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
```

[image: Linux fft result]
[image: matlab fft result]

Comment: I would check the result of `(double)rup[i]`. It is a cast from `unsigned char` to `double`, it may not work as expected.

Comment: @wowofbob, I have never experienced problems casting from `unsigned char` to `double`. Care to elaborate? I'd be interested in knowing more about that.

Comment: Is there a reason `rup` has 4096 elements, but you only copy 1024 of them to the FFTW input?

Comment: the cast seems to work as expected. The Matlab FFT is computed on the same double input values, created with the cast (double). With the same float (double) input series the results are quite different.

Comment: rup has 4096 elements because it is the maximum allowable series length. But in this case it is limited to no more than 1024 while copying into rup[] buffer.

Comment: I had a trouble when casted `char` to `size_t` in `c++`. As I remeber, `static_cast` was a workaround. I don't cleary remeber, have to dig into commits for details. So it's not a case here.

Comment: @wowofbob: if `char` is signed, then you might get an unexpected result when casting to an unsigned type. But `double` can represent every possible value of a `signed char` or an `unsigned char`, so I wouldn't expect issues in this cast here.

Comment: Can you apply your FFTW code to a very small array of all ones, something like 5 elements, and share the result?

Comment: Update: adding a window function before processing, results seems to be the same and look like the matlab results in the posted matlab graph. Does matlab force a preprocessing of input samples if no windows has been applied before ?
Thank you very much for your help.
Regards
Marco

Comment: How do you compute the FFT with matlab? Directly with [`fft`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), or through a spectrum estimation method (such as [`periodogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html), [`pwelch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html), [`spectrogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html), ...)?

Comment: We use directly fft. This choice to be the as close as possible to fftw results.